# Best way to implement "Post Card Sized" Web Pages

Tags: css

If I wanted to create a web page with content about the size of a post card, how would I go about positioning it on the screen?

Horizontally isn't an issue (margins auto); however, centering it vertically is a an issue.

What's the best way of centering the container vertically?  Javascript?  Should I even be trying to center it vertically, or would you in general prefer a page to start near the top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with CSS. Center a container DIV using 50% left and top. Then simply offset your contained postcard 50% of its width & height back.

```
<div id="postcard_container">
    <div id="postcard">
    Postcard here
    </div>
</div>

#postcard_container {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
#postcard {
    position:absolute;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    left:-400px;
    top:-300px;
}
```

Comment: Does this only cause problems in IE6? (If I shrink the window, we start to lose the top of 'postcard' div)

Comment: If you make the window smaller than 600px with the above code in IE6, the top of the container starts to become inaccessable

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to give in and go the tables route; it appears to be rendering correctly cross-browser:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
#content {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td align="center">
                <div id="content">
                    Postcard here
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```